# Bootstrap, fixed left offcanvas sidebar with scrollable content in the center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I want to create a template for a project that i am working on using Bootstrap and i have a problem with the behavior of the offcanvas sidebar. I want the sidebar to take all the space below the header and to not be scrollable. I have found two templates, that combined do what i want but i have a problem merging them as i am not very good with css. I have tried a lot to do but i can't figure how to do it. Here is a picture showing the desired functionality/behavior of the template i want to make:
[image]

Here are the two templates i have found:

- [Dashboard](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/)
- [Dashboard (with off-canvas sidebar)](http://www.bootply.com/render/128936)

And here is the code (HTML+CSS) of each template (stripped down) so you can easily figure out how they work:

**Dashboard - fixed sidebar**

- HTML

  ```
  <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
          <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
      </div>

  </div>
  ```
- CSS: [getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/dashboard.css](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/dashboard.css)

**Dashboard (with off-canvas sidebar) - scrollable**

- HTML

  ```
  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">

      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 main">
          <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
      </div>

  </div>
  ```
- CSS: http://textuploader.com/k6ae

Comment: `.main { height:700px; overflow:scroll; }`

Comment: @adaam i don't want to specify a height. i want the sidebar to dynamically take the remaining space.

Comment: good question, u managed to solve it?? i want to make similiar thing!

Comment: I have the exact same Problem, does anyone has a solution with BS4? Or should I open a new question?